# Extend Django User model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want the exact same behaviour as `django.contrib.auth.User` but I need to extend the model with some user preferences and profile specific fields.

I know I could eventually make two new models which could be

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User)
    age = SmallPositiveIntegerField()
```

and

```
class Preference(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User)
    background_color = CharField(max_length=6)
```

I don't know if it's smart to separate these things.

But I want to retrieve the user preferences on each page and if I use this approach by extending the `User` model with an `OneToOneField` it costs another sql query for each time I get `user.preference.background_color`.

I think it might be overkill to substitute the `User` model (or what) so what can I do?

Will proxy models be the answer?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way people (Two Scoops, for example) generally recommend doing this is by subclassing AbstractUser (or AbstractBaseUser if you want even fewer of the base user fields; baseuser just gives you password, login timestamp, and is_active).  You'd then just add fields as you would for a normal model and query them as you would for a normal model.